# discord.js bot only seems to work with localhost and goes offline otherwise

Tags: authentication, discord, discord.js, bots, singleton

I'm using `discord.js` version `14.11.0`. The goal is to have a button on my site, when clicked, to have my bot send a direct message to a user. This is the button click handler:

```
const discordClient = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] })
discordClient.login(MY_BOT_TOKEN)

const discordUser = await discordClient.users.fetch('1234567890')
discordUser.send({ content: 'hello world', files: [{ attachment: 'image.png' }] })
```

Anytime I click the button on my `localhost` version, the message gets sent to the discord user pretty much instantly. I have a staging site hosted with Vercel. The first time I clicked the button, the message got sent (although with a 10 second delay). Clicking the button anytime after and the message never gets sent. I also see that my discord bot is offline now. If I click the button from my `localhost` version, it works every time and the bot appears to be back online. But then using my staging site it never sends and the bot goes back offline.

Do I need to have the discord client use a singleton pattern and instantiate and login only once when my site first loads? And then the button click only calls the `.send()` method?

Comment: Is that all your code? Do you think the `discordClient` is ready right after you use `login`? Although it's weird that the first click goes through.

Comment: Yeah that’s all the code. Even without on ready event listener it works every time on my local version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would try to use the Discord REST API for this. You only have two endpoints to call:

- the one to [create a DM with a user](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#create-dm)
- the one to [send the message](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message)

If you can avoid creating a complete Discord.js client instance, it will be much lighter and easier to debug.